# Is the naming of Alan Tudyk's "Zootopia" character (Duke Weaselton) officially related to his "Frozen" character (Duke of Weselton)?

Tags: frozen, zootopia

Browsing through [Alan Tudyk's IMDb page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0876138/), I noticed he voiced a character in *Frozen*, [the Duke of Weselton](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2294629/characters/nm0876138). Slightly higher on the list is his vocal appearance in *Zootopia*, as [Duke Weaselton](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/characters/nm0876138).

I'm guessing this is not a coincidence. Is there an official source that confirms the naming of his *Zootopia* character is related to his *Frozen* character?

Comment: seems like an easter egg.

Comment: Definite Easter egg. In both his character's name is constantly mispronounced, leading him to issue a correction as his last line of dialogue.

Comment: Zootopia has a lot of little Easter Eggs! At one point, they find a street vendor selling DVDs and the Fox comments that "these movies haven't even been released yet!" One of them was named "Meowana". Disney just released Moana last month!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Alan Tudyk confirms this

In a red carpet interview for *Zootopia* he addresses this directly.

> Well, I have convinced Disney that I should be in everyone of their animated movies after *Wreck-It Ralph* and I've been doing a fairly good job of that, yeah. So in *Frozen* I was the Duke of Weselton and so in this movie I'm Duke Weaselton, because in *Frozen* I was always saying, everybody called him the Duke of Weselton, "he's Wesel from Weselton", and so the Duke Weselton, he's way up here so he's actually the Duke of Weselton, so he actually exists now.